# Ruby On Rails Page do not display table created with CKEDITOR

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

On an RoR opensource project I am working on, I have some pages where I can write description for Items thru CKEditor.

By default, Table is disable in CKEditor.

So, I enabled it in his config file, doing this:

```
config.removePlugins = 'liststyle,contextmenu,elementspath';
config.toolbar = [
      ['Bold','Italic','Underline','TextColor'],
      ['Format'],
      ['Outdent','Indent','-','JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight'],
      ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Blockquote','HorizontalRule'],
      ['Image', 'Link','Unlink'],
      ['Maximize','ShowBlocks'],
      ['Table'],
    ];
```

Removed "TableTolls" from "removePlugins", and add Table in toolbar.

Now, I can create Table in CKEditor. The problem is, when I save it, and go to the page where the new description with the table is... I got no Table at all.

I supposed it is because of some kind of parser or something that disable this function... But I don't know where to look at...

I am not good at those kind of think, any help is appreciate !

Regards

Comment: So... There is a lot of questions that I can't answer :) I supposed that if I knew that, I could probably solve it by myself as I would understood how it works :D. What I can tell, is that <table> is present in database! I just checked. But one more proof is that if I edit the content previously saved, the table is displayed correctly in CKEDITOR. Thanks for your help ! Do you know where/what I can search for to answer your questions?

Comment: I think I can answer that, I have a file called _item.html.erb and, in this file, I have: `<%= render :partial => 'rulebuilder/items/item_details', :locals => { :item => @item } %>
  <%= sanitize @item.full_description %>` is that part of an answer ?

Comment: One think interesting, maybe... is that, if I delete the "sanitize" before @item.full_description, it display html code in the description, and I can see the <table>

Comment: another intersting information, I think, is that in my application.rb file, I have this `config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = ['name', 'href', 'cite', 'class', 'title', 'src', 'height', 'width', 'style']`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mu is too short,

I added this :

```
tags: %w(table tr td), attributes: %w(id class style)
```

In the .rb file where I use sanitize. To have something like this:

```
<%= sanitize @article.body, tags: %w(table tr td), attributes: %w(id
class style) %>
```